# Pandas creating data frame from matrix in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary `Dict1` with keys as `Dates and Sims.`

`Dates` is an array with shape 100x1 and `Sims` has shape  100x5

I am trying:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe.from_dict(Dict1)
```

But errors out due to size of Sims. Is there a way I can create the DataFrame with each row of column Sims has size 5? i.e each row can be stored as list or array of size 5.

Edit:

```
Dict1['Dates']
array([datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 1, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 2, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2025, 12, 31, 21, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2025, 12, 31, 22, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2025, 12, 31, 23, 0)], dtype=object)


Dict1['Sims']

array([[ 63.89694316,  35.8551162 ,  40.36134283, 57.23648392,
         35.96607425,  61.166471  ],
       [ 47.94894386,  53.95396849,  48.94336457, 51.04541849,
         28.69973176,  49.78683505],
       [ 63.90314179,  43.29467789,  36.97811714, 52.33639618,
         45.24190878,  69.9059308 ]...]])
```

Edit2:

I am looking to create the dataframe such that I can perform the following operation:

```
print(df[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 0, 0)])

[ 63.89694316,  35.8551162 ,  40.36134283, 57.23648392,
                 35.96607425,  61.166471  ]
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(np.c_[Dict1['Dates'], Dict1['Sims']])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `Dict1['Dates']` as the index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Dict1['Sims'], index=Dict1['Dates'])
df.ix[datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Note that you should use the `df.ix[key]` indexer, since `df[key]` defaults to looking up a column, not a row.

---

Alternatively, if you really want a single column containing `list`s, make sure that `Dict1['Sims']` is a Python list, not a Numpy array before creating your data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sims': Dict1['Sims'].tolist()}, index=Dict1['Dates'])
```

The `{'Sims': ...}` construct tricks Pandas into interpreting the data as a single series of `list`s, rather than a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: I tried using df.ix[key] and it errors out even though that date is present in the 'Dates'. It's a great approach though if I could figure how to extract the data. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you post a minimal runnable example which reproduces the problem?

Comment: It was my bad. Your method is perfect.